# org.osgi import cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi, bundle, websphere-liberty

I am trying to get started with OSGI and create a basic bundle.

I created a bundle with activator in Eclipse (2019-06) and selected Liberty as the target runtime (the end goal is to create a Liberty extension)

It works fine, but when I convert it to Maven, Eclipse complains the org.osgi package cannot be resolved

I see this dependency is defined:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.wasdev.maven.tools.targets</groupId>
  <artifactId>liberty-target</artifactId>
  <version>19.0.0.9</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I tried adding this to the felix plugin with no luck.

```
        <Import-Package>
            org.osgi.framework
        </Import-Package>
```

After trying thing for a while I am ready to give up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `org.osgi` package cannot be resolved at run time or compile time? Please be aware that in Maven dependencies are resolved statically, whereas in OSGi bundles can be installed at run time and therefore dependencies are also resolved at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Add these maven dependencies for the OSGi specs.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>osgi.cmpn</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

You also have to configure the bnd-maven-plugin. So your imports are computed automatically. Alternatively you can use the maven-bundle-plugin. (You might already use this).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
    <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>bnd-process</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
           <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This covers the compile time resolution of your packages.

In addition you need to provide the correct bundles at runtime. This highly depends on how you define your runtime.

Some org.osgi package come from the OSGi framework itself. Others have to be installed as bundles. Be aware that you normally do not install the specs as bundles. Instead you install implementations that also bring the specs.

Comment: Thank you!

I guess I was expecting the conversion to be more automated.  I had to change the output directory for the test classes:
<outputDirectory>test_bin</outputDirectory>
That allowed me to right click, Maven > Update project.
and it picked up org.osgi from the liberty target dependency. I then added:
org.osgi.service.component.annotations
THANK YOU!